# Does the different texts within Vedas follow a certain hierarchy or any known order of authority?

Tags: scripture, vedas, brahmanas, samhita, aranyaka

In Vedas there are texts such as Aranyakas, Brahmanas, Upanisads, Samhitas etc. so in the case of differing views of various texts is there a certain order of which text view should be taken first?

For example, I have been told that if there is some contradiction between texts, Brahmana view should be seen as more authoritative than say Aranyakas but not Samhitas, I am not sure if this is universally true or a personal view?

I know there is a similar concept of hierarchy amongst scriptures when it comes to the classification of smriti and sruti texts i.e sruti texts are considered more authoritative. I am sure similar questions have been asked before but no seeming answers that I have found as of yet...

Comment: Vegas are not contradictory if they contradict we need to reconcile and understand our meanings on context with previous understanding

Comment: @PrasannaR you are right it is most likely down to the various interpretations. Perhaps conflicting views would be a more appropriate term to explain it.